# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, diccionarios

a partir de un fichero fasta, he creado un bucle para obtener como "claves" el nombre del organismos, y otro bucle para asignar a cada nombre la secuencia. Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

```
    import os
#def contar_nucleotidos(fasta="multipleSeqs.fa")
with open("multipleSeqs.fa","r") as documento: #abrimos el documento
  lines = documento.readlines() #Leemos el documento y lo guardamos en la variable lines
  multilista = dict() #creamos un diccionario que contendra nombre:secuencia
#Separamos por secuencias por formato
for line in lines:
  if line.startswith(">"):
    name = line.rstrip(os.linesep)
    multilista = name #asignamos el nombre del organismo a la diccionario
for i in multilista:    
  if not line.startswith(">"):
    seq = i.rstrip(os.linesep)
    multilista[line]= seq #asignamos la secuencia del organismo al nombre
```

y me da el siguiente error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-10e6b88c01cf> in <module>
     12   if not line.startswith(">"):
     13     seq = i.rstrip(os.linesep)
---> 14     multilista[line]= seq
     15 

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el primer `for` la variable `multilista` toma el valor de la variable `name` por tal motivo `multilista` deja de ser un diccionario y pasa a ser un string y de ahí el error. Es como si estuvieras haciendo `"hola"["algo"] = "otro"`

Answer (score 1):

Las personas que te respondieron están en lo correcto: estás convirtiendo multilista en una variable string --multilista = name--.

He hecho unas modificaciones al código para que se ajuste a lo que deseas.

```
import os
#def contar_nucleotidos(fasta="multipleSeqs.fa")
with open("multipleSeqs.fa","r") as documento: #abrimos el documento
  lines = documento.readlines() #Leemos el documento y lo guardamos en la variable lines
  multilista = dict() #creamos un diccionario que contendra nombre:secuencia
#Separamos por secuencias por formato
indice='' #contiene el indice actual del ciclo x
seq='' #Contiene la secuencia que se insertara al diccionario
for x in range (len(lines)):
  if lines[x].startswith (">"):
    name = lines[x].rstrip(os.linesep)
    indice=name 
    multilista[indice] = () #asignamos el nombre del organismo al diccionario
    for i in range(x+1,len(lines)): #El ciclo comenzara en el indice actual X + 1 hasta la longitud de la lista (lines)
      if not lines[i].startswith(">"):
        des=lines[i].rstrip(os.linesep) #
        seq=seq+des #se concatenan las lineas que se insertaran al diccionario
        multilista[indice]=seq #asignamos la secuencia al diccionario
      else: #en caso de que la linea comience con ">" limpia la variable seq y termina el ciclo. para pasar al siguiente indice.
        seq=''
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

aquí

```
multilista = name #asignamos el nombre del organismo a la diccionario
```

lo conviertes en string y por lo tanto `multilista` ya no hace referencia a un diccionario, puedes hacer algo como:

```
multilista[name] = name #asignamos el nombre del organismo a la diccionario
```

o

```
multilista['organismos']=[]
for line in lines:
  if line.startswith(">"):
    name = line.rstrip(os.linesep)
    multilista['organismos'] = multilista['organismos'].append(name)
```

Comment: Las dos opciones que me comentas me dan error. La primera me dice que el tipo NonType no se le puede aplicar la función append(). EL segundo me dice que ha cambiado el tamaño y que no es iterable. Al final he creado dos bucles independientes, uno me genera el nombre y el otro la secuencia, sin embargo, como la secuencia es más larga que una línea, me genera fragmentos al utilizar rstrip(os.linesep) oi intentando eliminar los saltos de linea con rstrip("\n"). Alguna idea?